# Perfect forwarding of variading template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I've written the following implementation for a generic signal/slot system:

```
template< typename... Args >
class Signal : NonCopyable
{
public:

    typedef std::function< void (Args...) > Delegate;

    void connect(const Delegate& delegate);
    void operator ()(Args&&... args) const;

private:

    std::list< Delegate > _delegates;
};

template< typename... Args >
void Signal< Args... >::connect(const Delegate& delegate)
{
    _delegates.push_front(delegate);
}

template< typename... Args >
void Signal< Args... >::operator ()(Args&&... args) const
{
    for (const Delegate& delegate : _delegates)
        delegate(std::forward< Args >(args)...);
}
```

Afterwards, I tested my class using the following simple cases:

```
Signal< int > signal;

// Case 1
signal(0);

//Case 2
int i(0);
signal(i);
```

Case 1 compiles without issue. Case 2, on the other hand, generates the following error under GCC 4.7.2:

```
/home/pmjobin/Workspace/main.cpp:1196:10: error: cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘int&&’
/home/pmjobin/Workspace/main.cpp:82:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Signal<Args>::operator()(Args&& ...) const [with Args = {int}]’
```

I understand the issue has something to do with perfect-forwarding (and my misunderstanding of the latter). However, I've inspired myself from the std::make_shared() & std::make_tuple() implementations and I fail to see any difference in the way I forward the variadic arguments to the delegates. The only notable difference being that both make_shared() and make_tuple() are function templates rather than a class template such as the Signal implementation above.

**- EDIT -**

In response to the various comments, here is a new version of the Signal class implementation which doesn't suffer from the aforementioned issues. Additionally, it is now possible to disconnect delegates using an opaque token returned by the connect function. The result might not be as flexible and powerful as other implementations out there (such as boost::signal), but at least, it has the benefit of being simple and lightweight.

```
template< typename Signature >
class Signal : NonCopyable
{
public:

    typedef std::function< Signature > Delegate;

    class DisconnectionToken
    {
        DisconnectionToken(typename std::list< Delegate >::iterator it)
            : _it(it)
        {}

        typename std::list< Delegate >::iterator _it;

        friend class Signal;
    };

    DisconnectionToken connect(const Delegate& delegate);
    void disconnect(DisconnectionToken& token);

    template< typename... Args >
    void operator ()(Args&&... args) const;

private:

    std::list< Delegate > _delegates;
};

template< typename Signature >
typename Signal< Signature >::DisconnectionToken Signal< Signature >::connect(const Delegate& delegate)
{
    _delegates.push_front(delegate);
    return DisconnectionToken(_delegates.begin());
}

template< typename Signature >
void Signal< Signature >::disconnect(DisconnectionToken& token)
{
    if (token._it != _delegates.end())
    {
        _delegates.erase(token._it);
        token._it = _delegates.end();
    }
}

template< typename Signature >
template< typename... Args >
void Signal< Signature >::operator ()(Args&&... args) const
{
    for (const Delegate& delegate : _delegates)
        delegate(std::forward< Args >(args)...);
}
```

Comment: `Args&&... args`  is basically `int && args`.

Comment: @Nawaz yeah, I missed that he explicitly specified it above. Nevermind what I just said. Yeah, perfect forwarding mainly only works when you let the template type be deduced.

Comment: What the OP needs to (or _can_) do is have a separate `Args...` for the `operator()`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Even then the design is flawed. Perfect forwarding and a list of `std::function` would not go along very well.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Perfect forwarding is a solution for overloaded function which accepts arguments as `X&&` and `X const&` (for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're explicitly specifying the template parameter as an `int`. As Nawaz mentioned, `Args&&...` gets expanded into `int&&` and you can't bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference.

The reason perfect forwarding works is that when you call a function (for example) without specifying the template arguments, they get deduced to either `&` or `&&` and then the references collapse (read about reference collapsing if you don't know what that is). You *do* explicitly specify it though, so you inhibit reference collapsing and screw it all up.

One thing you could do is give the `operator()` it's own list of template arguments:

```
template<typename... Args2>
void operator ()(Args2&&... args) const;

...

template< typename... Args >
template< typename... Args2 >
void Signal< Args... >::operator ()(Args2&&... args) const
{
    for (const Delegate& delegate : _delegates)
        delegate(std::forward< Args2 >(args)...);
}
```

This way you can let reference collapsing take care of it for you.

Comment: It is the same problem: now if I declare `s` as `Signal<int&&> s;` and then call it as `int i =10; s(i);` then it will not compile!

Comment: @Nawaz then don't declare `s` as `Signam<int&&>`

Comment: @Nawaz you can call functions that are compatible. You couldn't call a function `void s(int&&)` like `int i; s(i);` otherwise, so you can't do it here either.

Comment: If we have a function as `void s(X&&)` then we also have its overload `void s(X const &)`, for example. So we can call `s` as : `s(X());` and `X x; s(x);` both!

Comment: @Nawaz the class he's writing only works with functors which all take the same parameter type.

Comment: Yes. that is what is flawed. I mean what if I have `void f(int&&)`? How should I declare `s` then? As `Signal<int&&>`, right?

Comment: @Nawaz yes and that would compile, and why do you expect to be able to call it like `int i; s(i);` if your function is `void f(int&&)`? Like I said, you couldn't call it that way otherwise.

Comment: So it is the same problem, as the OP has. Ask him, not me. :P

Comment: @Nawaz no it's not. He has `Signal<int>` and can't pass an int by value which is legal C++, and this fixes that problem. You're wanting a `int&` to turn into an `int&&`. What you're saying is not what he's doing in his code that doesn't compile.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: What he *really* needs to do is stop having the `Signal` use a variadic template. Do what Boost.Signal does and have `Signal` take the function type ala `std::function`'s template argument. That way, operator() is where the variadic template goes.

Comment: @NicolBolas well, since (if you factor in this my suggestion) the operator() is already a variadic template, why does it matter besides saving typing? I don't think it would be more flexible would it?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: You don't get the point. What is the point of such a class which doesn't do what can be done otherwise? It works for `s(0)` but not for `s(i)` even if it would work otherwise. As I said before, the very design of the class is flawed which is why it doesn't seem to be useful for real world problems.

Comment: @Nawaz You're right, I don't understand. If you factor in my changes, it _does_ work for `s(i)` when it would work otherwise. No?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: No. If I've `X&&`, then I also have `X const&`, as is usually the case in the real world. The design of the class is such that it would work only for one, which is not a solution. The class should be able to call overloads based on the type of the value (rvalue or lvalue).

Comment: @Nawaz then you have to use more complicated things to store multiple types in a single container. While that is more flexible I think for this questioner it is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks for the suggestion. It is indeed cleaner to directly specify the function signature for the delegate. Beside, it allows the delegate to have a non-void return value which improves flexibility a bit.

Comment: @SethCarnegie + Nawaz : Thanks for the enlightening discussion. I have a gained a better understanding of perfect-forwarding.